# What does bash out mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have been watching a stand up comedy show on Netflix of a British comedy named Daniel Sloss.

What does **bashed out** mean in this context?

I imagine Christmas morning as a parent is very difficult, especially if you've young children.
It's Christmas morning, seven a.m. They **bashed out** of the rooms, they run downstairs, they're so happy.

Comment: Seems like a typo for *dashed*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please [edit] your post to provide context—where did you come across this sentence? What is the surrounding text or the broader situation? It's also important at this site to demonstrate your initial efforts at research; for example, did you check *bash* in a dictionary? Without these, it's quite impossible to give you a definitive answer, and we can only speculate as to whether the meaning is literal or figurative, or if it is simply a typographical or usage error. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: This is a simple typo - vote to close

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific meaning for "bash out" in the dictionaries - other than "write (an essay etc) quickly" (which is irrelevant here).

Bashing means hitting a person or a thing or bumping into something. Bashing out of a room would mean fighting one's way out of it. It could mean forcing doors open or pushing other people out of the way.

It is unlikely in this case that the children had to use physical force. "Bash out" is probably just a figurative usage expressing their eagerness to leave their rooms.